# Re-write infinite number of sub-directories

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file can I rewrite a URL that has a possibly infinite number of sub-directories to a new one?

The first "directory" they request should always be the same.

eg.

`/FOOBAR/this/is/my/url`

to

`/myscript.php?params=this,is,my,url`

and

`/FOOBAR/these/are/some/more/ones/cant/you/see`

to

`/myscript.php?params=these,are,some,more,ones,cant,you,see`

Do I have to write out a massive line to capture as many directories as I think would be requested or is there a way to capture all regardless of the number?

I only know the basics of .htaccess like rewriting a directory and I know a little regex but not enough to do this on my own. I don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the entire path as a parameter to your `index.php` file. Then, in the php file, use `str_replace` to change `/` to `,`:

#### `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [L]
```

#### `index.php`

```php
$params = str_replace( '/', ',', $_GET['params'] );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks pretty easy when you do it like that. I forgot to mention in my question that the first "directory" will always be known and I can't rewrite every single request to the domain, otherwise files like the 404, /images, /scripts, /contact/index.php won't work. Maybe I can add a `RewriteCond` to only rewrite when the first directory matches the one I want?

Comment: @Jared Use `RewriteRule ^FOOBAR(/.*)$ ...` where `...` is the same as above